# Execute complex mongo JSON query using C# mongo driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following mongo shell query:

```
{'field':'FieldOne','value':'FieldOne','category':'categoryOne'} , { 'Color' : { '$elemMatch' : { 'Value' : 'Green' } }}
```

Is there any way to execute same query using **C# mongo driver**?. I have tried using below `C#` code, but only the first one is getting executed:

```
 BsonDocument query = BsonDocument.Parse("{'field':'Overall','value':'Overall','category':'LoggedIncidents'} , { 'Priority' : { '$elemMatch' : { 'Value' : 'P1' } }}");
 QueryDocument queryDoc = new QueryDocument(query);
 var result = collection.Find(queryDoc).ToListAsync().Result;
```

The first item (`{'field':'FieldOne','value':'FieldOne','category':'categoryOne'}`) is being executed but not the second one (`{ 'Color' : { '$elemMatch' : { 'Value' : 'Green' } }}`).

Comment: following a quick look: {'field':'Overall','value':'Overall','category':'LoggedIncidents'} , { 'Priority' : { '$elemMatch' : { 'Value' : 'P1' } }} is not a valid json query. it has two roots.  try {$and [{'field':'Overall','value':'Overall','category':'LoggedIncidents'} , { 'Priority' : { '$elemMatch' : { 'Value' : 'P1' } }}]}

Answer (score 0):

You are using it in find command if i'm not wrong. 
the first "{}" is what the filter condition for find is. next set of parameters are essentially to show/hide the fields you need.
so if you want to filter by value of array "green" you can do this.

```
 db.objects.find({"color":{$elemMatch:{value:"green"}}})
```

should give you the results you are looking for. but if you want to specifically show/hide fields, you can do

```
 db.objects.find({"color":{$elemMatch:{value:"green"}}},{"field":1})
```

is this what you want to attain?